# ng-click event not firing correctly afer updating to bootstrap popover 3.2

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

In my project, bootstrap popover is used to show a span with ng-click event (Using a directive to compile popover content and then binding popover to element). I had bootstrap 3.1.1 and it worked fine. Each time the popover was opened, ng-click event was triggered. Now I have moved to bootstrap 3.2.0 and popovers in my project are not working correctly. It just works until the first time we show and then hide popover (by clicking on page) and after that, when I open the popover again it shows the content correctly but not firing the event. It seems that somehow the event is removed from element. I have tried onclick event instead of ng-click and it works correctly in both versions.

```
            <a ng-repeat="b in list"
               role="button" class="btn">
                <input ng-if="someCondition"
                       sample-popover type="hidden"
                       popover-content="{{ b.content }}" />
            </a>
```

I have this html and Popover content is just a simple span with ng-click.

```
.directive('samplePopover', function ($compile) {
return {
    restrict: "A",
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var options = {
            content: $compile(attrs.popoverContent)(scope),
            placement: "bottom",
            html: true,
            trigger: 'click',
        };
        $(element).closest('a').popover(options);
        scope.test= function () { 
//this is called with ng-click
        };
    }

}});
```

Comment: Let me just take out my crystal ball to see your code so I can help you

Comment: updated post with a sample code

Comment: is the popover destroyed or just hidden with css?

Comment: just hide: $(this).popover('hide'). And it shows the popover each time correctly, just the event on span not working

Comment: There is few possible reasons, the popover or just the element with ng-click is covered by other DOM element, or popover scope has changed somehow so the method you try calling doesn't exist